# filter by row_number in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, row-number

how can I filter the row_number ==1 in the following query:

```
query = session.query(Foo, func.row_number().over(
        partition_by=Foo.foo_field, order_by=desc(Foo.foo_date_time)).label("row_number"))

    query = query.filter(Foo.time_key <= time_key)
    # query = query.filter(row_number == 1)
    result = query.all()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found it:

```
    row_number_column = func.row_number().over(partition_by=Foo.foo_field, order_by=desc(Foo.foo_date_time)).label('row_number')
    query = self.session.query(Foo)
    query = query.filter(Foo.time_key <= time_key)
    query = query.add_column(row_number_column)
    query = query.from_self().filter(row_number_column == 1)
```

Answer (score 10):

It can also be done using a subquery:

```py
sub_query = session.query(
Foo,
func.row_number().over(partition_by=Foo.foo_field, order_by=desc(Foo.foo_date_time)).label("row_number")
)
sub_query = sub_query.filter(Foo.time_key <= time_key).subquery()
query = session.query(sub_query).filter(sub_query.c.row_number == 1)
```

It basically generates an equivalent SQL Statement as adding the row_number as a column.

Compiling the statement.

```py
sub_query = session.query(
Foo,
func.row_number().over(partition_by=Foo.foo_field, order_by=desc(Foo.foo_date_time)).label("row_number")
)
sub_query = sub_query.filter(Foo.time_key <= time_key).subquery()
query = session.query(sub_query).filter(sub_query.c.row_number == 1)

str(query.statement.compile())
```

Will generate the following:

```sql
-- SubQuery function
SELECT anon_1.time_key, 
       anon_1.foo_field, 
       anon_1.foo_date_time, 
       anon_1.row_number 
FROM (
        SELECT  foo.time_key AS time_key,
                foo.foo_field AS foo_field, 
                foo.foo_date_time AS foo_date_time, 
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY foo.foo_field ORDER BY foo.foo_date_time DESC) AS row_number 
        FROM foo 
        WHERE foo.time_key <= %(time_key_1)s
    ) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.row_number = %(row_number_1)s
```

**UPDATE**: Keep in mind that **Query.from_self** method is deprecated since SQLAlchemy 1.4 and will be removed in 2.0 [according to the official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.from_self)

In case there's someone using it, you can check the [migration guide for this case](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-20-query-from-self)

Comment: For some reason, using `subquery()` results in model class being lost ands a row is returned as a `tuple`. Anyway to make it retain its type? e.g. `Foo` after running `query.all()`

Comment: @phoxd. Not sure if it will behave the same in current versions, I remember trying to adding the whole object to sub-query to keep reference of model class with no additional params, but it was a long time ago and not exaclty a common use case for me, you would have to test it out.